# Pros/Cons to updating in place

Tags: performance-tuning, memory

There are often times when I have to update a list.  The following is an example:

```
businessAssoc= JoinAcross[x2, businessAssoc, {Key[Treaty], Key[Effective]}, "Left"];
```

I could set another symbol to the answer, but sometimes I want to keep the name of the symbol the same.  I worry, however, that updating in place like this might cause some sort of internal problem to the kernel, especially if it involves a large list.  I did some brief tests and saw that it used less memory when I updated in place (I set $HistoryLength=1).  The time for the calculation didn't seem to change.  Are there any dangers to doing this?

Comment: Should be no problem. There isn't really that much of "in-place" updating in this case - you just store the end-result in the same variable (but the r.h.s. had to create a copy etc for its computation). Usually, this term is used when you update some inner part of a given expression, stored in a variable, without copying the entire expression - in such cases, one may get more substantial benefits in terms of performance / memory consumption (this isn't to say that you used the term incorrectly: what you did certainly can be also called in-place updating).